# sftp real time warning in solaris

Tags: solaris, sftp

Suppose I have two solaris servers, A and B, and I am connecting from one server to another using sftp.

Suppose B tries to connect to A using SFTP.

Then How to detect in A the sftp request sent by B ? Is there any way by which I can have a message displayed on the client console(like putty) through which I am logged in to A stating "B is trying to connect to you"?

I thought of running a particular script ,which searches for an sftp in the list of processes, continuously between small spans of time but I think that would not be accurate.

Now can I send a message back to B from A as soon  as B succeeds in logging in that will be displayed in client screen through which I am logged in to B?

Can all these be accomplished by shell scripting? 
I generally get to use solaris, so is there a solaris specific answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `wall` to send a message to all terminals:

> SYNOPSIS
>          wall [-n] [-t timeout] [-g group] [message | file]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          wall  displays  a  message, or the contents of a file, or otherwise its standard input, on the terminals of all currently logged in users.

You can configure `sshd` to use PAM (if that is available under Solaris) and use `pam_exec` (https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec) to get notified every time an SSH login takes place. At that stage it is probably not determined yet, though, whether it is an SFTP session. You could start a script in the background which somehow checks for SFTP.

Comment: How to send back to the user who just logged in ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh I am not really familiar with PAM but this information must be passed somehow, probably as an environment variable or as an parameter to the binary to be called.

Comment: Ok..I will try it once ..don't know if solaris has it or not